# Show that if a series converges then limsup is 0

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n < \infty$, i.e. bounded. For $k \geq 1$ let $N_k$ denote the size of $A_n = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n \geq 2^{-k}\}$. Show that

$$\displaystyle
\limsup_{n\to \infty} 2^{-k}N_k = 0.
$$

What I've tried to do is proving the contrapositive. Suppose $\limsup_{n\to \infty} 2^{-k}N_k > 0$ then there is a subsequence $\{2^{-k_n}N_{k_n}\}_{n \geq 1}$ that is larger than a certain constant $\epsilon > 0$., i.e. $N_{k_n} \geq 2^{k_n}\epsilon$ for all $n \geq 1$. (In particular $N_{k_n} \geq 1$).

So then $\sum_{n \in A_{k_1}}a_n \geq \epsilon$, and $\sum_{n \in A_{k_2}}a_n \geq \epsilon$, and so on but the problem is overlapping elements in $A_{k_1}$ and $A_{k_2}$ (i.e. they are not disjoint!), so I can't stack the sums to be larger than any $M \in \mathbb{R}$.

I guess that $A_{k_2}$ has at least $(2^{k_2}-2^{k_1})\cdot \epsilon$ elements not in $A_{k_1}$, which means:

$$\sum_{n \in A_{k_2}\backslash A_{k_1}}a_n \geq \epsilon \cdot 2^{-k_2}\cdot (2^{k_2}-2^{k_1}) = \epsilon (1-2^{k_1-k_2})$$
but that does not seem to be big enough to show the overall series diverges.

Any amendments/direct proof or other method that is a better or simpler approach?

EDIT: I guess I figured it out by noting that $1-2^{k_1-k_2} \geq \frac12$, so I can perhaps still stack the series to be larger than any $M \in \mathbb{R}$ by careful justification for $A_{k_n}$. Let me know if this is the case, thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to write that $\sum_{n\geqslant1}a_n\color{red}<\infty$?

Comment: yea thanks I fixed it